# Return type of an inline function

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, c, cocos2d-iphone

This method in Cocos2d:

```
/** Returns opposite of point.
 @return CGPoint
 @since v0.7.2
 */
static inline CGPoint
ccpNeg(const CGPoint v)
{
    return ccp(-v.x, -v.y);
}
```

Why does it say 'CGPoint' after inline?  Why not

```
static inline ccpNeg(...
```

?

Comment: @Javoid - maybe you need to read a basic book on ObjectiveC or C or C++ programming.

Comment: Already answered.  Why must I wait 10 minutes to click an answer?

Comment: Probably to let other people have a fair share in answering the question.

Comment: Yes, but then when a question has a good answer, it makes others waste their time reading it.  Good and bad I guess.

Comment: Stephen C wasn't nice, but it is a fact that your headline refers to "return type" and the comment on the function says "return CGPoint" and yet you're asking why the return type is there and why not simply omit it, which does suggest some sort of basic misunderstanding.

Comment: @Jim: The original title of the question was actually "Why is this inline function written this way?".

Comment: @Ben Thanks, I should have read the edit. But that doesn't really change the point ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the function wants to return a CGPoint.

Comment: Oh, well that was obvious.  =(  I hate it when I miss something like that.

Answer (score 2):

`static` specifies the function's linkage and `inline` hints to the compiler that the function should be inlined. Neither of these is the function's return type, which every function must have (even if it's `void`). `CGPoint` is the function's return type.

Answer (score 0):

`CGPoint` is the return type of the function.

If you just wrote `static inline ccpNeg`, the compiler wouldn't know what type of object the function returns (`static` and `inline` are just modifiers telling the compiler that it should [inline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function) the function; you still need a return type regardless).